# pandas.read_csv skip rows until certain string is found

Tags: python, r, pandas, fread

in `R`, there is a common function called `fread`, which is used to read in tsv/csv/... files.
It has a super useful argument called `skip`, which allows you to specify a string, and the row in which that string is found is then used as the header (useful if you specify a substring of the column names row)

I was wondering if there is a similar function in python because it seems extremely useful.

Cheers!

Comment: Have a look at pydatatable; it should offer the same functionality for fread

Answer (score 1):

A technique I sometimes use (e.g. to filter faulty data, and when none of the other wonderful capabilities of `pandas.read_csv()` seem to address the case at hand) is to define a `io.TextIOWrapper`.

In your case, you could write:

```py
class SkipUntilMatchWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, f, matcher, include_matching=False):
        super().__init__(f, line_buffering=True)
        self.f = f
        self.matcher = matcher
        self.include_matching = include_matching
        self.has_matched = False

    def read(self, size=None):
        while not self.has_matched:
            line = self.readline()
            if self.matcher(line):
                self.has_matched = True
                if self.include_matching:
                    return line
        return super().read(size)
```

Let's try it on a simple example:

```py
# make an example
with open('sample.csv', 'w') as f:
    print('garbage 1', file=f)
    print('garbage 2', file=f)
    print('and now for some data', file=f)
    print('a,b,c', file=f)
    x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 3))
    np.savetxt(f, x, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

Read:

```py
with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as f_orig:
    with SkipUntilMatchWrapper(f_orig, lambda s: 'a,b,c' in s, include_matching=True) as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  2  7  8
1  7  3  3
2  3  6  9
3  0  6  0
4  4  0  9
```

Another way:

```py
with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as f_orig:
    with SkipUntilMatchWrapper(f_orig, lambda s: 'for some data' in s) as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  2  7  8
1  7  3  3
2  3  6  9
3  0  6  0
4  4  0  9
```